# It is possbile to have ALLOWED_HOSTS different configuration for some urls?

Tags: django

I want to have `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` for some urls but for the rest I want it to be `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[".example.com"]`.

For csrf we have `@csrf_exempt`

For cors we have the signal `check_request_enabled`

But for ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: I think it's not implemented yet. Ref [**Ticket #27806**](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27806)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to go would be to write a middleware, that will check the request url and set `ALLOWED HOSTS`. You'll need to add this middleware at the **top** of `MIDDLEWARES` section in settings file. Try something like below:

```
from django.conf import settings

def simple_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        if request.META['PATH_INFO'] == "your_logic":
            settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
        else:
            settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com']
        response = get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    return middleware
```